# AWS API SDK export for Android does not accept body content on POST

Tags: android

I can use POST to call the AWS API Gateway OK when there is no body.  When there is a body I get this error, where 9 is the length of the String body:

> com.amazonaws.mobileconnectors.apigateway.ApiClientException: expected
>   0 bytes but received 9 (Service: null; Status Code: 0; Error Code:
>   null; Request ID: null)

When I used Postman, I set up Body html key/pair as Body/BLUE and it worked fine.  I wonder why the export SDK for Android doesn't accept a body content.  Thanks for the help.

My code is:

```
final MyAPIClient client = factory.build(MyAPIClient.class);
String body = "Body=BLUE";
byte[] content = body.getBytes("UTF-8");
ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest(client.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .withPath("/vote")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .withBody(content);

ApiResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you send 9 bytes of data while your request headers indicate you'll send 0 bytes of data (as the `Content-Length` isnt set).

While validating your request the server gets aware of that fact and therefore gives you given error.

From my point of view you should call `addHeader` a second time and set the `Content-Length`.

```
ApiRequest request = new ApiRequest(client.getClass().getSimpleName())
                    .withPath("/vote")
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                    .addHeader("Content-Length", [insert byte count here])
                    .withBody(content);
```

For more information on how `Content-Length` works please refer to https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html (Scroll to 14.13 Content-Length)

Comment: This resolved the issue!  The http link is a nice read.  I have been stuck with this for 2 days.  Thanks a lot, Fabian.

Comment: @SteveTran your'e welcome. If the answer solved the problem you should "accept" it by clicking the checkmark below the votes to indicate the question as solved. Cheers.

Comment: I have checked it.  Sorry, I am new to this :)

Comment: @SteveTran no need to be sorry, everybody here started small ;)
Upvoting, Downvoting, Close-Votes and Accepting answers is an important part of how Stackoverflows "user moderation"-Thing works